# Changing the size of a UICollectionViewCell when interactive

Tags: swift, uikit

How do you change the size of a cell (probably using `.transform`) when using it interactively, for example dragging the cell around to reorder it?

I have a gesture recogniser hooked up to my view controller, that handles the interactivity.

```
  @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
      guard let selectedIndexPath =
        imageCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: imageCollectionView)) else {
          break
      }
      imageCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
      imageCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(
        gesture.location(in: gesture.view!)
      )
    case .ended:
      imageCollectionView.performBatchUpdates {
        self.imageCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
      }
    default:
      imageCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
  }
```

And the movement delegate method as follows:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                      to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let image = selectedItems?.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row) else {
      return
    }
    selectedItems?.insert(image, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
  }
```

When I hold and enable interactivity for a specific cell, I want the cell to grow 25% bigger, to indicate it's being held and interactive - can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way,

If you use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

add relevant logic

```
var theIp: IndexPath?


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
     if indexPath = theIp{
          return normalSize 
     }
     else{
          return biggerSize 
     }

}
```

to make it work, just use `func reloadItems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])`

---

To do more customization,

You shall use custom `UICollectionViewLayout`,

by `override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?`

& `override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?`

---

Use `drag and drop`, maybe more fit